# how to add href link in email content when sending email through smtplib

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib

I'm sending email through below code:

```
msg = MIMEText(u'<a href="www.google.com">abc</a>')
msg['Subject'] = 'subject'
msg['From'] = 'xxx'
msg['To'] = 'xxx'

s = smtplib.SMTP(xxx, 25)
s.sendmail(xxx, xxx, msg.as_string())
```

what I want to receive is

> [abc](http://www.google.com)

what I actually received is:

```
<a href="www.google.com">abc</a>
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html  What you're attempting to do needs to be sent via MIMEText(html,blah)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should specify [`'html'`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.mime.html#email.mime.text.MIMEText) as the subtype -

```
msg = MIMEText(u'<a href="www.google.com">abc</a>','html')
```

Without specifying the subtype separately , the subtype defaults to `'plain'` (plain-text). From [documentations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.mime.html#email.mime.text.MIMEText) -

> class email.mime.text.MIMEText(_text[, _subtype[, _charset]])
>
> A subclass of MIMENonMultipart, the MIMEText class is used to create MIME objects of major type text. _text is the string for the payload. **_subtype is the minor type and defaults to plain.**

(Emphasis mine) .

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me :)

```
email_body = """<pre> 
Congratulations! We've successfully created account.
Go to the page: <a href="https://www.google.com/">click here</a>
Thanks,
XYZ Team.
</pre>"""

msg = MIMEText(email_body ,'html')
```

O/P:
Congratulations! We've successfully created account.

Go to the page: [click here](https://www.google.com/)

Thanks,

XYZ Team.

Comment: I didn't need the <pre> tag, and when I sent the email through gmail's python api, the <pre> tag changed the look of the font, which wasn't what I was going for. specifying 'html' in the MimeText constructor was sufficient for me